# #php Deprecated: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() should not be called statically in C \xampp\htdocs

Tags: php

1. hola por favor podrian ayudarme estoy en php con estos dos errores que me salen
   al tratar de ingresar, el primero me dice el método no estático
   Conexion::conectar() no debe llamarse estáticamente en
   C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\modelos\usuarios.modelo.php en la línea 14
2. y el segundo error y que no medeja entrar al sistema dice Índice
   indefinido: contraseña en

   C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php en la línea 25

> ASI SE MIRA EL  ERROR

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

```
    **
```

**> Y ESTE ES EL CODIGO DE usuario.controlador**

**

```
 <?php

    class ControladorUsuarios{

    /*=============================================
    INGRESO DE USUARIO
    =============================================*/



     public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

       if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])){

       if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) &&
         preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])){

          

          $tabla = "usuarios";

          $item = "usuario";

          $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

    $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

    if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["ingPassword"]){

            $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] = "OK";

                echo '<script>
                
                window.location = "inicio";

                </script>';



          }else{

               echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger"> ERROR de usuario, vuele a intentarlo</div>';


          }
         
          }
     }

    }




    }





    ?>
```

**Y ESTE ES EL CODIGO DE deusuario.modelo**

```
    <?php

    require_once "conexion.php";

    class ModeloUsuarios{


    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR USUARIOS
    ============================================*/

      static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla,$item,$valor){

     $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");



        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();


     }

    }




    ?>


<!-- end snippet -->


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSIwz.png
```

**

> ESTE ES EL CODIGO DE CONEXION

**<?php

class Conexion{

```
public function conectar(){


    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=predictario1",
        "root",
        "");

    $link->exec("set names utf8");

    return $link;



}
```

}

?>

Comment: ¿Es la [misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/550457/deprecated-non-static-method-conexionconectar-should-not-be-called-statical)?.

Comment: si la otra me dijeron que estaba mal escrita espero que como esta ahora me puedan ayudarme

Comment: Tenés que compartir el código del archivo conexion.php para ver la clase

Comment: Hola, ya lo añadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en el archivo `conexion.php` falta definir el método `conectar` cómo ***estático***:

```php
// Añadir static al método
public static function conectar(){
...
}
```